# Chromatic number of induced subgraphs as upper bound to the chromatic number

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

**Motivation:** At the Erdős100 conference in Budapest András Gyárfás presented some interesting conjectures. One of them was the following:

Given that in a graph $G$, every subgraph $H$ formed by taking the induced subgraph on the vertices of a path, has chromatic number at most $r$. Is it true that then the chromatic number of $G$ is bounded by a function of $r$?

**Question:** Are there any results such that: If in a graph $G$, every induced subgraph with a special property has chromatic number at most $r$, then the chromatic number of $G$ is bounded by $f(r)$?

Of course i would like to avoid special properties that enable induced subgraphs with a lot of vertices, like the property that "This induced subgraph contains all but one vertex".

**EDIT:**  Let $G$ be connected.

Comment: I don't understand your restriction in the last paragraph... Is the trivial "connected" with $f(r)=r$ acceptable?

Comment: No. That would do exactly the thing i was trying to avoid with my last paragraph. I will edit the question to avoid these kind of answers. I'm sorry about the badly formulated restrictions, i was trying to get results similar to the open problem in the second paragraph.

Comment: OK. I think I had misread your last paragraph. Note that traceable graphs, as proposed by Gyárfás, can be quite large.

Comment: Now it's my turn to not understand things. I was trying to show that for example the property that "$H$ has $n-1$ vertices" is strong enough to bound the chromatic number of $G$ with $r+1$, but is not so interesting. Because it is  very different from the open problem presented in the 'motivation'. It relies on the size of $H$

Comment: Yes, I just figured out you used $n$ for the size of $V(G)$ and not some fixed constant. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. It is a very widespread convention in my country, i will not make this mistake again. Also, if it would be just a constant, it wouldn't be true, since there are graphs with arbitrarily big chromatic number and girth. (If the girth is large enuogh, every induced subgraph of constant size is a forest.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a very similar question to that of Gyarfas which is well-known, still open, and notoriously hard.

**Question:** Is it true that if every triangle-free induced subgraph of $G$ has chromatic number at most $r$, then $G$ has chromatic number at most $f(r,\omega)$, where $\omega$ is the clique number of $G$?

A positive answer to this question would directly imply the following conjecture of Gyarfas:

**Conjecture:** There is a function $g$ such that every graph with no odd induced cycle of length at least 5, and clique number at most $k$, has chromatic number at most $g(k)$.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood something, but isn't the complete graph on $n$ vertices a counterexample to your first question? (Every triangle-free induced subgraph has at most $2$ vertices in the complete graph.)

Comment: You're of course right, my bad. You have to consider graphs of bounded clique number. I edited the post